# what are the differences/comparison between the two popular java Caching frameworks hazelcast cache vs ehcache?

Tags: java, performance, caching, hazelcast, ehcache-3

Looking for comparison between two caching frameworks --> Hazelcast v3.10.5 vs ehcache v3.6.1, also please throw light on performance.

Two popular cache frameworks evolved over a period. we are in now 2018.

We choose a caching framework for better performance, distributed, scalability, fault-tolerant instead of hitting the database for every call.

Which one has better performance when we choose write-through/synchronous calls for an application, let us say with 1000 user requests per second.

Some initial research elements:

Read about Hazelcast is distributed, scalable, resilient.

Ehcache is a standalone framework, whereas ehcache with terracotta is distributed.

Please refer Link: [Is it possible to implement distributed caching using of Ehcache without Terracotta Enterprise Suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992899/is-it-possible-to-implement-distributed-caching-using-of-ehcache-without-terraco)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an apples to apples comparison, for ehcache is a standalone cache in a Java application whereas Hazelcast is a distributed system which can run both embedded in application or as a remote service like client-server. Both will have different level of performance. Ehcache does not provide any fault-tolerance whereas Hazelcast has backups etc.

It basically depends on what exactly you are looking for - a standalone cache for your application that does not share its data with other application instances or a distributed system that stores data that can be accessed by multiple applications.

Comment: Firstly I am looking for distributed, fault-tolerance cache, preferably freeware. Looks like ehcache with terracota supports distributed caching.